# Where are these songs used in Ferris Bueller's Day Off?

Tags: soundtrack, ferris-buellers-day-off

I just got the Ferris Bueller's Day Off OST from La La Land Records, but not all songs from the movie are on there due to licensing issues, so I set out to put the songs that are in the film but left off the soundtrack back in, so I checked the soundtrack from the end credits but couldn't find where the following are used within the context of the film:

- The Bridge 
  by Feargal Andrews, Frank Kearns, Eoin McEvoy, Wayne Sheehy 
  Performed by Cactus World News 
  Courtesy of Mother Records Ltd.
- Children of the Revolution 
  by Marc Bolan 
  Performed by Violent Femmes (as The Violent Femmes) 
  Courtesy of Warner Bros Inc.

Comment: I see there are many votes to close this question, but before you do, can you please tell me a more appropriate place to post it?

Comment: Don't just put this on hold and walk off. While I agree that it may be trivia, and does not fit the standards of this site, can you please be helpful and tell me where I can go to have it answered as I politely requested above? It cannot be reworded in order to fit the site, because it is my question.